# Crossbrowser Input element CSS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have an input box and a button on a website which i'm trying to align correctly in my CSS. Initially it looked fine on firefox 22.0, safari 5.1.9 and chrome 29.0.1547.57(mac) but not chrome 28.0.1500.95 on windows so i added some code that only targeted chrome , however now it looks odd in safari and chrome (mac) but fine in firefox and chrome on windows. How would i fix this?

This is what happens: http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/image_zpsd746de67.jpg

CSS code:

```
input#image {
            position: relative;
            top: 20px; 
            }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
            input#image {
                        position: relative;
                        top: -2px;
                        left: 106px;
                    }
                                                      }
input#box {
          position: relative;
          width: 30px;
          height: 25px;
          top: 25px;
          left: -60px;
          border:none; 
         -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
         -moz-border-radius:5px; 
          border-radius:5px; 
         -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
         -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
          box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset;
          text-align: center;
          }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
            input#box {
                      position: relative;
                      width: 30px;
                      height: 25px;
                      top: 30px;
                      left: -60px;
                      border:none; 
                     -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
                     -moz-border-radius:5px; 
                      border-radius:5px; 
                     -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
                     -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset; 
                      box-shadow:0 0 5px #666 inset;
                      text-align: center;
}
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information of the browser version ? Also, you haven't implemented all vendor specific classes, such as `-ms-` and `-o-`

Comment: p.s. I'm quite new to all of this

Comment: I think you would need to specify the margin and padding too as those have different presets on each browser.

Comment: i have added the browser versions at the top

Comment: what exactly do you mean by implementing all vendor specific classes?

Comment: As you suggest cross browser, vendor specific CSS must be implemented to provide better support on cross browser display.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor how would i do that exactly?

Comment: Here is a cheatsheet : http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/

Comment: see this http://css-tricks.com/styling-texty-inputs-only/

Comment: seee this http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/

Answer (score 0):

try make this

css

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
#first {
}
#first li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
#first li a {
    background-color: #333333;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
#first li a:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}
```

html

```
<ul id="first">
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why i would need a list for correctly aligning my text box and button?